# How to make floating text onclick like cookie clicker?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

[image]

When clicking the "big cookie" in cookie clicker, there is a popup showing how many cookies you earned (+276.341 septillion in this image), which slowly moves upward and fades out.

I wanted to implement a similar feature in my game, I sucessfully made the moving up and fading out part with css animations, however, there will be more than one of these numbers showing up at once, so how do I clone elements? And how do I make these show up at the cursor position?

Comment: you want to make those texts clickable?

Comment: Those text appear on click and doesn't need to be clickable

Comment: Please put just enough of the code you have so far into your question so we can run it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I only did the css animation part, I don't know how to clone elements for one to show every click, and also don't know how to make it show at cursor position, that's why I'm asking here. So there's aren't any relevant code to put here

Comment: Sorry, without seeing your current structure and code we can't help. You do have some as you have said in your question that you successfully implemented the moving up and fading out. Without this any answer is just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what technologies you are using so here is how to do it with vanilla HTML and JS.
You say you already made the HTML & CSS, so turn your HTML into a template

```html
<template id="floating-text-template">
  <!-- your existing code -->
</template>
```

Now in your javascript, clone the template on each click

```js
function click(event) {
  const template = document.getElementByID('#floating-text-template').content.cloneNode(true);
  const element = template.querySelector('.floating-text') //replace class with yours
  element.style.left = `${event.clientX}px`
  element.style.top = `${event.clientY}px`
  document.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: The template can be put just anywhere in your HTML, I typically put mine at the bottom of the <body>

Comment: You can read more about the [HTML template tag here](https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2020-06/template-tag/)

Comment: Got an error, but after changing to to `element.style.left = event.clientX +'px'` it works

Comment: Extra question, how do you prevent accidentally highlighting the floating text when clicking too quickly

Comment: Sorry for got to add CSS units, updated answer. @Mewtwo2387 To prevent highlighting the text, add `user-select: none` in your CSS and you won't be able to select the text.